# How to troubleshoot routes

Tags: routes, routing

Very new to Craft CMS...

My first route, which i think is very simple, is not working, i'm getting a 404 error.  How can I troubleshoot routing?

My settings:

If the URI looks like this:

```
databases/
```

Load this template:

```
library-database-demo-section/index.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `/` at the end of `databases/` and it should work.

Technically, `index.html` is not required either, so you could just use `library-database-demo-section`.